# How to update a still referenced primary key in db2

Tags: sql, db2, primary-key

Background: I am programming an application that uses Java for DB2 (V9.5 for UNIX) access.
For testing I made this:

```
CREATE TABLE country(
name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
population BIGINT,
  PRIMARY KEY(name)
);

CREATE TABLE city(
name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
country VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(name),
  FOREIGN KEY(country) REFERENCES country(name)
);
```

And here is my problem:

DB2 doesn't support "ON UPDATE CASCADE" and still referenced primary keys aren't allowed to change. So how can I change a name of a country while it is still used by a city?

I am not searching a solution that realize this within Java (There I could insert the new value, update affected cities and delete than the old value) There must be a way to do this in DB2. Hopefully.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your design. Generally, a primary key is not supposed to change after insertion. What you might want to do is this:

```
CREATE TABLE country(
  id BIGINT,
  name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  population BIGINT,
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

CREATE TABLE city(
  id BIGINT,
  name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  country_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(id),
  FOREIGN KEY(country_id) REFERENCES country(id)
);
```

Optionally, you can still make the `name` columns `UNIQUE`

Comment: I also thought about this solution, but is this really the only way? This would blow up later queries and the taken space is unnecessary because the name of a country is unique a good primary key candidate.

Comment: Why not? While it might seem a little bit more effort at table-design time, you can avoid loads of problems similar to the one you've had, later. Before the notion of `identity` was introduced in SQL, primary keys were really `ID`'s and used as such. When you think about foreign keys referencing them, it becomes obvious that they shouldn't change again. Your original design is fine only if you don't ever want to change that name again. If you worry about long queries, then you can name your IDs like this `country_id`, `city_id`. That way, you could use the `NATURAL JOIN` syntax

Comment: PS: another reason why you shouldn't update primary keys is for performance. Even if it were possible, you'd probably get table locks in many dependent tables...

Comment: @user773233 - if country is unique and a good primary key candidate - why do you need ot change it.  Watch the news more often "country" is actually quite a dynamic attribute.

Answer (score 1):

If you are stch with the current schema then you can do it in three steps:--

```
INSERT INTO COUNTRY VALUES ('Peoples Democratic Republic of Judea', 3000000 - 299 );

UPDATE CITY SET COUNTRY = 'Peoples Democratic Republic of Judea' 
WHERE COUNTRY = 'Free Federal Judean Peoples Republic' ;

DELETE FROM COUNTRY WHERE NAME = 'Free Federal Judean Peoples Republic' ;
```

N.B. `- 299` to account for purge of reactionary running dogs.